# Json.Net: Using SelectToken to get a value without knowing an element name?

Tags: .net, json.net

I have a simple JSON file which i need to get the value of a token, i have tried using SelectToken but the problem is that the name of the elements are dynamic. Here is my JSON file

```
{
    "name": "testdata",
    "items": {
        "myItemName": {
            "located": true
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get the value of "located" (above), If you see the element name "myItemName", this is dynamic and not fixed. So I did try using the dot notation of SelectToken.

I came up with something like so, but it didn't work - problem is the [0]

```
        bool located = (bool)jsonObject.SelectToken("items.[0].located");
```

Within Items, there can be more than 1 dynamic element, so for example, this is valid.

```
  {
        "name": "testdata",
        "items": {
            "myItemName": {
                "located": true
            },
            "myOtherItemName": {
                "located": true
            }
        }
    }
```

So looking above, you can see I have "myItemName" and "myOtherItemName", I would like to get the values of "located" in each one using somekind of foreach

Is this at all possible ? Using SelectToken?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
string json = @"
{
    ""name"": ""testdata"",
    ""items"": {
        ""myItemName"": {
            ""located"": true
        },
        ""myOtherItemName"": {
            ""located"": true
        }
    }
}";

JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach (JProperty prop in jsonObject.SelectToken("items"))
{
    string name = prop.Name;
    bool value = (bool)prop.Value.SelectToken("located");
    Console.WriteLine(name + " = " + value);
}
```

Output:

```
myItemName = True
myOtherItemName = True
```